# Checking additive closure for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \{f \mid f:X \to K\}$ be a vector space over the field $K$. Let $U = \{f \mid f(5) = 1+f(4)\}$. Is this a subspace of $V$?

Well, clearly $U$ is non-empty. Take $f(x) =x$. Now additive closure? Let $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ where $f,g \in U$. Then $h(5) = (f+g)(5) = f(5) + g(5) = 2 + f(4)+g(4)$. How do I know if this is or is not in $U$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a subspace since $0\notin U$... (unless $K$ is a field with 1 element).

Comment: I wouldn't joke about fields with one element here, that's only a source of confusion.

Comment: @JasonCarr wasn't joking, but the consequence of $0\in U$ is $0=1$, which can be true (only) in this situation...

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you.

Comment: @Netchaiev Yes but generally speaking $0 \neq 1$ is a field axiom, so fields have at least two elements. There is not actually a field with one element.

Comment: @JasonCarr I know there exists a quarrel about that matter... The point was just to avoid a discussion on that peculiar case... But ok, it can be rephrased as "It is not a subspace [...] (since a field has at least 2 elements)"...